# Service account can't connect to a Google Sheet using domain wide delegation

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

I have a spreadsheet on our company Google Drive that I would like to be read by a service account. I've been stuck on this for some time now but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

For that I created a service account, enabled the domain wide delegation and added the needed scopes ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' and 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly') in the G Suite Admin panel, matching the client id of my service account. I created a key for this service account and save it in a json file (file is key_sa.json).

Despite that, when running the following code, it fails:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH = 'key_sa.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('user@company.com') 
delegated_http = delegated_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
delegated_credentials.refresh(delegated_http)

service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=delegated_http) # credentials=credentials)
```

The error message I got for the last line is:

```
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.
```

Any hint as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following scopes as mentioned below:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
```

These scopes must be added to both in your code and the API permissions in Google Admin Security setting.

```
...spreadsheets.readonly
...spreadsheets
```

both the above permissions behave differently and so both need to be added.